# Zod parse: infer type of output in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I am writing a generic function that takes a Zod object schema, and returns the result of parsing an object with that schema (or undefined if it failed to parse).

I want the return type of the function to be the same as the type of the passed in schema.

I tried the following:

```
export function parseURLProps<T extends z.ZodSchema<O>, O extends object>(schema: T) {
  const props = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('props');
  if (!props) {
    showError("Expected url parameter 'prop'");
    return;
  }

  const parse = schema.safeParse(JSON.parse(props));
  if (!parse.success) {
    showError(
      "Didn't find the expected schema in the url query parameter 'prop'.\n" +
        fromZodError(parse.error)
    );
    return;
  }

  return parse.data;
}
```

It correctly fails if I don't pass an object schema.
Calling it with `parseURLProps( z.object({example: z.string()}) )`:
I expect the return type to be: `{example: string} | undefined`.
Instead, I get: `object | undefined`.

I can get it to work if I explicitly define return type to be `z.infer<T>`, or set a default value for the O generic type `O extends object = infer<T>`.

Edit: I was able to get the result I expect with `parseURLProps<O extends object>(schema: z.ZodSchema<O>)`, but the question still remains:
Why does `parseURLProps<O extends object>(schema: z.ZodSchema<O>)` and `parseURLProps<T extends z.ZodSchema<O>, O extends object>(schema: T)` give different results?

I want to understand why it didn't work without the above modification, and to know if there's a better way of doing this.
Thanks.

Comment: Other generic type parameters aren't used as inference sites, so TypeScript can only use the parameter `schema` and its type of `T`. Since `T` is a `ZodSchema<O>`, and `O` cannot be inferred, `O` is `object`, which is why the return type is `object | undefined`. In your fix you've edited in, TypeScript can infer `O` from the type of the `schema` parameter directly, so the return type is `O | undefined`.